# Is there a source that lists halachic sugyot in a given masechta with suggested rishonim to compare?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, product-recommendation

I'm looking for a source that I was once shown that outlines the major halachic sugyot of a masechta along with the important rishonim to know to be aware of the gist of the machloket and any pertinent chakirot.

Comment: Sounds like a big book

Comment: The Raza d'Shabsi does this for a couple of masechtos, but I don't know of anything that does this more broadly and specifically aliba d'hilchesa.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.2a.1?with=Halakhah&lang=bi

In every massechet, if you tap the amud, it opens a windows with many resources (halakha, mishna, commentary, musar, etc.).  Kol tuv!

Comment: For machloket, in the same web-site, you can find Nishmat Adam, Chokhmat Adam and Chayei Adam.

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to dafyomi.co.il which summarizes the sugya then brings relevant Rishonim and Poskim. It is organized Daf by Daf.

See an example [here](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/sukah/halachah/su-hl-036.htm). You can get to other topics from the [homepage](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/).